# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting the following error. `restaurantData.itemArray` contains array of `ProductData` objects and I am trying to filter it with `id` as follows. I wonder what I am doing wrong in my implementation.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.'

```
+ (NSString *)menuItemForItemId:(NSString *)itemId
{
    ProductData *restaurantData = [ProductData restaurantDataInstance];

    NSString *item = @"";

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", kItemId, itemId];
    // the error is thrown in the following line
    NSArray *filteredArray = [restaurantData.itemArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if ([filteredArray count] > 0)
        item = [(NSDictionary *)[filteredArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:kItem];

    return item;
}
```

---

Here is my `ProductData` class if it is needed.

**ProductData.m**

```
#import "ProductData.h"

#define kTitleKey        @"pName"
#define kPriceKey        @"price"
#define kIdKey           @"id"

@implementation ProductData
@synthesize pId, pImage, pPrice, pName, itemArray;

+(ProductData*) restaurantDataInstance {
    static ProductData *restaurantDataInstance;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(!restaurantDataInstance){
            restaurantDataInstance = [[ProductData alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return restaurantDataInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        if (!itemArray || !itemArray.count){
            itemArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDict{
    self = [self init];
    if (self){
        self.pId = [aDict objectForKey:@"id"];
        self.pPrice = [aDict objectForKey:@"price"];
        self.pName = [aDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: "kItemId" seems like constant. What is its value?

Comment: it is just a constant string `id`

Comment: *ProductData* don't have *id* as a variable. Maybe you have to filter it with pId

Comment: BTW: Objective-C isn't an hungarian language. Please, respect the naming rules.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I do not get your point. Could you please clarify a little further in detail?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ProductData` does not have a property named `id`, from your sample code I can see that it has `pId`

The line below tries to access a property named `id`, which does not exist.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", kItemId, itemId];
```